# Is there a way i can recover my .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, terminal, recovery, data-recovery, dotfiles

Is there a way I can recover my .bashrc file? I accidentally removed the contents within the file and saved.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files, among others.

Comment: What did you have in it? Was it just a bunch of functions you had? You can use `declare -f` to see all the functions defined in your current environment. `alias` will give you all your aliases in the same way. `env` will give you all your environment variables, though many of those aren't set up by your `.bashrc`.

Comment: I had my my prompt variable, my alias, and some functions

Comment: @jeremysprofile do i just enter declare -f as a command in the terminal?

Comment: @jeremysprofile I didn't delete the file. I deleted the contents from the file and saved by accident

Comment: To use the current shell to recover your prompt command, run `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` and save the results.

Comment: @John1024 i ran that command and nothing happened. The only thing that showed up was "update_terminal_cwd"

Comment: Having something "show up" is the _opposite_ of having "nothing happen."  For more info on what did show up, see ["What does update_terminal_cwd do in the terminal of OS X"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139807/what-does-update-terminal-cwd-do-in-the-terminal-of-os-x)

Comment: @DontePalmer: Revert to the backup. I hope you are doing regular backups, and use a texteditor which cretaes backup files. Otherwise, the old wisdom applies: _No backup - no mercy_.

Answer (score 0):

Once the file has been saved and the session with the editor is closed, you can not recover the contents of the file. However, if you haven't rebooted yet and a terminal session in which the .bashrc was sourced still remains, you can recover variables and functions from this session.

If your file had something like this:

```
# content of .bashrc
export DERP=hi
function _test { echo "test"; }
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

You can get the content of the functions with `typeset`, the variables from `env` and aliases with `alias`. You can get your prompt variable from `$PS1`.

```
$ typeset -f _test
_test () 
{ 
    echo "test"
}
$ env | grep derp
derp=hi
$ alias
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
$ echo $PS1
\u@\h $
```

EDIT:
You might want to create a git repository for your .bashrc, .vimrc and equivalent files. It seems to be quite common to do so, since you probably want to use the same file on different systems.